# Elasticsearch popularity fallback

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a fallback in my queries to a popularity ranking if no hits are found. Every week I calculate a `popRank` field based on the number of times the doc is visited in the last month. This means that not all docs will have a `popRank`, only the ones visited in the last month.

The query below does not work with the `must` clause even though there are items that contain that category

```
GET /index/docs/_search
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "terms": {
                    "body": [<array of keyword strings>]
                }
            }, {
                "constant_score": {
                    "filter": {
                        "match_all": {}
                    },
                    "boost": 0
                }
            }],
            "must": [{
                "terms": {
                    "category": ["DIY"],
                    "boost": 0
                }
            }],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }, {
        "popRank": {
            "unmapped_type": "double",
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }]
}
```

This query is supposed to return resulting docs if the `should` clause is fulfilled, if not then the popularity ranking will take over, in either case it must be filtered by the category. This works if something other than the `match_all` returns results but does not work if only the `match_all` returns results.

This is an example doc.

```
{
    "_index": "index",
    "_type": "docs",
    "_id": "Fridays",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "id": "Fridays", 
        "body": "text...",  
        "category": [
            "DIY",
            "Kitchen"
        ],      
        "popRank": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no ES 1.5.5 release, did you mean 1.4.5?

Comment: I've tried with ES 1.4.5 and I do get a `sort` element in the response with the above request. Can you show the response you get?

Comment: sorry corrected ES version to 1.5.1, added an example of the doc minus text body since there are not hits for the body.

Comment: Not sure the sort has anything to do with it. I was able to reindex everything with ES 1.4.4 and the sort does not appear, and it returns nothing like 1.5.1 so the version is not the problem. If I remove the `must` clause I get results or if I move  `category`  to the `should` section I get results. I even tried making  `category` in `must` an **exact** match for at least one item and no luck.

Comment: have reworded the question to remove references to unimportant non-clues